# Is it possible to remove UIImage that is drawn in a UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, drawatpoint

I drawed an `UIImage` into an `UIView` using `drawAtPoint` method

```
  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

if (wipingInProgress) {
    if (imageRef) {
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, rect.size.height);
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

        CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, imageRef);
        CGImageRelease(imageRef);

        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, rect.size.height);
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    }
    [myImage drawAtPoint:location blendMode:kCGBlendModeDestinationOut alpha:0.4];
}
```

Basically this `myImage` acts like an eraser and clears out my `UIView`.

I would like to know if I can undo this process,so that the `myImage` which is drawn into `UIView` will get removed and I get my `UIView` previous state.

Right now, I'm calling the `[self setNeedsDisplay];` to undo my erasing action,so that view gets redrawn again with the oldImage and it works fine, all my drawing  is cleared out by this call.!!!

Is there any other way to undo my drawing action?
Is there a way to remove the `myImage` which is drawn into my `UIView`?

Note:

**my UIView previous state** = UIView with pre-saved image(this image I get from an array) drawn into it

**all my drawing** =  Let's say I am erasing the image by my finger,here the drawing is considered as the erased part. Whereever I touch the screen , I draw the image at that point which gives the impression that image in the uiview is cleared out at that point.

Comment: Yes I can do it. Actually that is what I am doing right now. I want to know if there is a way to remove the image so that, when I erase too much, I want only to remove some part of erase so that remaining part of erase is still on my view!!!

Comment: where as setneedsDisplay just clears out everything which I dont want to.

Comment: updated the question @beyowulf

Comment: Hello, I dont understand your question very well. I have a drawing app where after each touch I get a printscreen and put in an array. If the user press undo button I get the last image from array